# Use VHDL Generics To Choose Entity

Tags: vhdl

I have a VHDL design with two architectures named `fast` and `slow`.  I'd like to be able to choose between them at simulation/elaboration time using the command line and generics.

I cannot figure out how to choose a configuration, that is to instantiate a component with the architecture I want, using VHDL generics.

Is there a way to do this or do I need to use a `generate` statement and hardcode the chosen architecture?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out you cannot use the generic to control a configuration statement.  Instead use `generate` to pick architectures using a generic:

```vhdl
LIBRARY ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity dut is
    generic (
         SPEED : string := "fast"
     );
    port(
        clk : in std_logic;
        reset: in std_logic;
        start: in std_logic;
        done:  out std_logic);
    end entity dut;


architecture dutarch of dut is

    component delay is
        port (
            clk : in std_logic;
            reset: in std_logic;
            start: in std_logic;
            done: out std_logic
        );
    end component delay;
    begin
     d1g: if (SPEED = "fast") generate
          d1 : entity work.delay(fast)
           port map (
                clk     => clk,
                reset   => reset,
                start   => start,
                done => done
            );
        else generate
          d1 : entity work.delay(slow)
            port map (
                clk     => clk,
                reset   => reset,
                start   => start,
                done => done
            );

        end generate;
end architecture dutarch;
```

Comment: **Turns out you cannot use the generic to control a configuration statement.** VHDL doesn't have a configuration statement. There are configuration declarations, configuration specifications and component instantiations with instantiated *declared* configurations. The latter can be conditionally instantiated although likely not supported by any extant synthesis tool, see IEEE Std 1076-2008 11.7 Component instantiation statements, 11.7.1 General. Your shown method surmised in the question should work but isn't verifiable lacking a [mcve] nor is it clear what fast and slow mean here.

Comment: So they should be 'd1a' and 'd1b'?

Comment: The joys of commenting using a handheld device. [No, d1 labels are on concurrent statements in the generate statement body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWMNJ.jpg). There are no alternative labels here (between `if` or `else` and `generate`). You don't need the component declaration and do need the  supplied entity `dut` and it's architectures previously analyzed for your answer to be verifiable.